# How to get the character and operator in a string in C# using Split

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split, radgrid

I have requirement where I have to perform calculation on textbox based on formula. I wanted to know how to get the field name and operators separately so that i can bind it in formula textbox. Example : {FieldName1} + {FieldName2}+{Fieldname3} is the formula and i want the data which contains braces separately as they will taken as field name and **+** symbol separately. I dont know how to get this. Here is my code-

```
    DataTable dt_main = GetTable();
    DataTable dt_AutocalculatedColumns = GetCalculatedColumn();
    string AutoGeneratedColumnName = string.Empty;
    string Formula = string.Empty;
    string FLD1 = string.Empty;
    string FLD2 = string.Empty;
    string FLD3 = string.Empty;
    if (dt_AutocalculatedColumns.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row_field in dt_AutocalculatedColumns.Rows) 
        {
            AutoGeneratedColumnName = row_field["FieldName"].ToString();
            Formula = row_field["AutoCalculatedFormula"].ToString();
            string[] words = Formula.Split(' ');
            foreach (string Eachword in words)
            {
                // what to do here i am not getting
            }
        }
    }
    protected DataTable GetCalculatedColumn()
    {
        SqlConnection con= newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ExcelLikeConnnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("My Select Query", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: In this instance, wouldn't splitting on `'+'` be more appropriate than splitting on `' '`?

Comment: What kind of answer exactly are you looking for? One that writes the calculation code for you?

Comment: What value will the Formula variable have? does it contain the whole expression? shouldnt you split on '+'? what do you want to do after splitting?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using only `+` operator then you should split on it and not on `' '`. To make sure that you don't have field name with spaces use trim.

```
string[] words = Formula.Split('+');
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    words[i] = words[i].Trim();
}
```

Of course in this situation you can't have `+` in field names.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ:

```
string formula = "{FieldName1} + {FieldName2}+{Fieldname3}";
string[] words = formula.Split('+')
    .Select(w => w.Trim(new char[] {' ', '{', '}'})).ToArray();
```

This will split the string `formula` and trim each entry so that you are just left with your field names.  The resulting output would be a 3 element array containing `FieldName1`, `FieldName2`, and `FieldName3`.